# Common class to be used for Volley and Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit

Can anyone help me out on how can we use a common class for network calls which can be used by both Volley and Retrofit with few minimal changes? So that in the future, if I have to change to Retrofit or back to Volley, it should be feasible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just declare an API access interface and implement it in two specific ways?

Comment: can you give me an example with code snippet

Comment: This is a trivial design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a wrapper class.

Basically, you need to create a contract for network calls. You'll have to define which kind of parameters you are going to send, how much data you are going to get, and which kind of callback system you are gonna use. You should not use any Volley/Retrofit class at this level in order to be able to switch the stuff. this kind of approach is useful everytime you may need to decouple your app from any framework, either for safety (your actual concern), testing, etc. Let's see an example:

```
public class Request<X>{

protected HashMap<String, String> headers;
protected HashMap<String, String> queryParams;
protected X body;
private String url;

//manage fields

}

public class Response<X> extends Request<X>{

private int statusCode;

//manage fields

}

public class restApi{

public interface OnRestOperation<X>{
void onSuccess(Response<X> operation);
void onServerFailure(Response<X> operation);
void onClientFailure(Response<X> operation)
}

public interface NetworkLayer{
void makeCall(Request<X> request, Map<String, OnRestOperation> listeners);
void removeListener(String listenerName);
}

private HashMap<String, OnRestOperation> listeners;
private NetworkLayer networkLayer;

public restApi(NetworkLayer networkLayer){
this.networkLayer = networkLayer;
}

public restApi setNetworkLayer(NetworkLayer networkLayer){
this.networkLayer = networkLayer;
return this;
}

public void call(Request<X> request, OnRestOperation<X> aListener, String listenerName){
listeners.put(getListenerName(request), aListener);
networkLayer.makeCall(request, listeners);
}

public deleteListener(String listenerName){
listeners.remove(listenerName);
networkLayer.removeListener(listenerName);
}

}
```

NetworkLayer is where retrofit/volley/whatever should be implemented. Obviously you can go Rx/eventbus instead of listeners, add threads, memoization, etc.

Comment: Thank you was looking out for the same